# Norms on unitization of a Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a non-unital Banach algebra, and let $A^+$ be its unitization. Then $||(a,z)||_1=||a||+|z|$ is a Banach algebra norm on $A^+$.

Can we also make $A^+$ a Banach algebra by giving it the norm $||(a,z)||_p=(||a||^p+|z|^p)^{1/p}$ for $p\in(1,\infty)$?

**Remark:**
My original post was also about $||(a,z)||_{op}=sup\{||ab+zb||:b\in A,||b||\leq 1\}$ but then I realized that it may not even be a norm in general.

Comment: $\|(a,z)\| _{op} =sup\{\|ax+bx\|: b \in A, \|b\| \leq{1} \}$ will be a norm if your $A$ is a C*-algbera and with this norm $A^+=A×\mathbb{C}$ will be a C*-algebra containing identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in general.  For instance, suppose $A=\mathbb{C}$ with the standard norm.  Then (via a change of basis $(a,z)\mapsto (a+z,z)$) we can identify $A_+$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$ with coordinatewise multiplication, and your norm with $\|(a,b)\|=(|a-b|^p+|b|^p)^{1/p}$.  Now consider the elements $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(1,1/2)$.  We have $\|x\|=1$ and $\|y\|=2^{(1-p)/p}<1$, but $\|xy\|=\|x\|=1>\|x\|\|y\|$.

Comment: But I'm considering non-unital $A$. Does it make a difference?

Comment: "Non-unital" normally means "not necessarily unital".  In any case, you can apply this argument to any $A$ which contains an idempotent element of norm $1$ (just make that idempotent play the role of $1\in \mathbb{C}$ here).

Comment: It looks like you're considering a different norm from the one I asked about. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm considering the same norm, but am identifying $A_+$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$ in a different way than the obvious way so that the multiplication is just $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac,bd)$.  If you use the obvious way of identifying $A_+$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$, then my elements $x$ and $y$ are $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.